# How can I import e-mails to CiviCRM?

Tags: email, import, civicase

I would like to be able to select and import one or more e-mails from my external inbox, into the Activities of a Case, creating a new activity. Is this possible and if yes, how? Who is familiar with this and how is it done?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using MS Outlook or Gmail? We've written a couple of extensions/plugins which allow the functionality you've described.

A couple of posts will give you some background to the project

https://vedaconsulting.co.uk/outlookforcivicrm-release
https://vedaconsulting.co.uk/outlookforcivicrm-civicase

We've also recently done some work allowing you to sync CiviCRM Groups to mailing lists within your outlook client - blog post to come.

The CiviCRM extension and the outlook plugin can be found in our git repo along with installation instructions.

https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.outlookapi

Thanks Erik and Pete for the nudges!

Comment: Thanks Parvez! I expect they will use Outlook and we now where to find you :-)

Comment: Can you provide links here to help complete this answer?

Comment: We will use MS Outlook indeed. @Petednz, I am not sure what you mean by providing links, what kind of links do you mean?

Comment: I think Pete means that it would be nice if Parvez adds links to his extensions and plugins :-)

Comment: Have added some links to the answer, happy to help get you up and running if needed.

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM can be configured to read an email into an activity. The section *Email-to-Activity processing* in the chapter [Email system configuration](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/advanced-configuration/email-system-configuration/) of the manual describes this in detail. But as a short summary, it entails configuring an IMAP email box and process it with a scheduled job.

Comment: The downside of that would be that you import all emails in the box I think? The requirement here is to import a single email when I as a user think it is useful rather than all emails in the box.

Comment: Typically you set up a special inbox for this purpose, and then forward or bcc there to import them.

Comment: Can also configure to only pull a specific subfolder.

Comment: @Coleman - if you forwarded it, wouldn't it get attached to the wrong contact?

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/dahndy/leveraging-civicrm-email-to-activity-processing-in-gmail) gives a good overview of an excellent way to import only certain tagged emails into CiviCRM.  I found it very helpful and clearly written.

Comment: YOu may be interested in this too: https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/improvements-to-inbound-emails-to-cases-in-4730

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/improvements-to-inbound-emails-to-cases-in-4730) explains how we delivered some improvements to 'inbound email' so that they could include the case id in the subject, and have the email added to the relevant case